# how to fix issue with youtube player not showing up with full width & height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube-api

Below is sample of my  code im trying to use playlist where the player will be in full width and height but for some reason it's not working. So what i'm trying to accomplish is the player will be on full page without anything else. Nothing else will show up  [example link](https://www.youtube.com/v/OrV--SA-z74) here is [link for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2m8teact/) any help will be appreciated.

COPY of code

```
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body onload="load()" style="background-color:white">
<script type="text/javascript">
var playlisturl = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL704DA9FE5E10160C?v=2";
var playlisturls = ["http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL704DA9FE5E10160C?v=2"];
var pause_playlist_text = "Pause playlist (loop current video)";
var embed = true;
var autoplay = true;
var vwidth = 400;
var vheight = 500;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://youtube-playlist-randomizer.valami.info/seedrandom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://youtube-playlist-randomizer.valami.info/playlist2-min.js"></script>
<div id="control_buttons" style="display:none">
  <button style="display:none" id="nextbutton" onclick="next()">Play next</button>&nbsp;<span style="display:none" id="videosleft"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<button  style="display:none" id="previousbutton" onclick="previous()">Play previous</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <button style="display:none" id="pauseplaylist" onclick="pause_playlist()">Pause playlist (loop current video)</button>  <button style="display:none" onclick="reshuffle()">Reshuffle</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('pauseplaylist').style.display = "none"
</script>

<div id="video">
  <p>Loading playlist...</p>
</div>

<div class="videowrapper">
  <div id="myytplayer"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var ytplayer;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
{
  ytplayer = new YT.Player('myytplayer', {
    height: vheight,
    width: vwidth,
    videoId: '8tPnX7OPo0Q',
    events: {
      'onReady': onYouTubePlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onytplayerStateChange,
      'onError': onytplayerError
    }
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the container width and height 100%, Check this out :

```
#myytplayer {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.videowrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, you could use tubular: http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/
>   as tubular is quite suffisticated, i extracted the necessary code
>   for you. (renders the video in full width and height, NOT stetched, similar to a css cover image)
>
> html code:

```
<div id="player-container" style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div id="player" style="position: absolute">
</div>
```

> here comes the complete youtube API cover style stuff, extracted from
>   tubular. jquery is needed. Also the standard youtube html5 iframe api
>   code must be included - as given here:
>   https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

```
 var ratio = 16 / 9;
 window.onPlayerReady = function (e) {
     resize();
 }

 $(window).on('resize', function () {
     resize();
 })

 var resize = function () {
     console.log("resize");

 var heightcorrection = 0,
         width = $(window).width(),
         pWidth, // player width, to be defined
         height = $(window).height() - heightcorrection,
         pHeight, // player height, tbd
         $videoPlayer = $('#player');        

     if (width / ratio < height) { // if new video height < window height (gap underneath)
         pWidth = Math.ceil(height * ratio); // get new player width
         $videoPlayer.width(pWidth).height(height).css({
             left: (width - pWidth) / 2,
             top: 0
         }); // player width is greater, offset left; reset top  

     } else { // new video width < window width (gap to right)
         pHeight = Math.ceil(width / ratio); // get new player height
         $videoPlayer.width(width).height(pHeight).css({
             left: 0,
             top: (height - pHeight) / 2 
         }); // player height is greater, offset top; reset left

     }

 }
```